# html menu does not work on mobile devices

Tags: asp.net, mobile, menu

I have a asp.net project.
Here is my menu :

```
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li>
                    <a href="/Default.aspx">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/Terms_Of_Services.aspx">Terms of Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/Partners.aspx">Partners</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="/Contact_Us.aspx">Contact Us</a>
                </li>

                <li style="float: right;font-size: 25px;position: relative; top: 5px;right: 12px;">
                    Automatic cryptocurrency exchange
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

The problem is this menu does not work on mobile devices.
I removed last `<li>`.
But problem is still there.
How can i fix this menu to work with mobile devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inspect you website using remote debugging android devices and I found out that couple of Telerik files are unable to load. Kindly check it out

Use `chrome://inspect/#devices` to remotely debug your website on mobile

[image]